# Location Context changes country between Jobs and Company Pages

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location

Just noticed this on the [UK](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk) site.

If I go to http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/location/london, I see jobs for London, UK. 
[image]

If I click the Company Pages tab...
[image]

my location context has been changed to London, Ontario...

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if they outsource the location finder to Apple? They should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: Careers seems to be haunted by such geostuffs. Surely the devs themselves must be sick enough of this to do it once and for all.

Comment: @GrantThomas Yepp. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed. Thanks for letting us know.

Problem was: it worked on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/location/london but not on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/uk/jobs/location/london. So "/uk" was the troublemaker ... some url parsing didn't account for those extra 3 characters, and the location became "on/london" after clicking on the tab. :/

Now the real question of course is: why are there no developer jobs in [London, Ontario](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London,_Ontario)?

Comment: [meta-tag:status-completed] then, or waiting to confirm first?

Comment: yepp, status-completed. Was waiting for the green tick.